# Can i overridge parents footer.php file in my functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change the footer contents on my website. I want to be able to override the parents current `footer.php` file. I'm doing it at the moment from my `functions.php` file as shown below. Which isn't my whole `functions.php` file but only the relevant section.

```
<?php

//footer override 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','footer_override',30);
function footer_override(){
    wp_enqueue_script('footerscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/php/footer.php');
}
```

I'm getting a GET error as shown below

```
https://linton59.co.uk/wp-content/themes/simpleshift-child02/php/footer.php?ver=4.9.1
```

But the file structure does exist.

Comment: add `footer.php` file into your `child theme` first level folder( directly into your child theme folder ). After copy all content from parent themes `footer.php` file and paste it into `footer.php` file of your child theme. Then just change/replace that part, which you want

Comment: worked a charm, thanks man. Post an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `footer.php` file into your `child themes` first level folder ( directly into your child theme folder ):

- {your-website-folder}

  - wp-content

    - {your-child-theme-folder}

      - `footer.php`

After copy all content from `parent themes footer.php` file and paste it into `footer.php` file of your child theme. Then just change/add that part from child theme's file, which you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all "wp_enqueue_script" is used to enqueue scripts (javascript files).
And your message is not conveying a clear message, you can simply replace contents by editing footer.php file itself

Comment: There is no way of avoiding editing the parents footer.php file?

Comment: you can use a chid theme and edit the part you want to change as suggested by Samvel above